# iTextPDF 7 - Table of content with clickable page numbers

Tags: java, pdf, itext, itext7

I'm trying to create a table of content with iTextPDF 7 in Java from existing PDFs.
I've tried to use `Link link = new Link()` and `PdfAction.createGoTo(PdfExplicitDestination.createFit(pageNum))` but to no avail.
I can't link the page number/row in TOC to the respective page in the end PDF (after merging).

The documentation on their website only gets me so far and I'm out of ideas.

What is the correct way to create a TOC for existing PDFs and how to implement it correctly?

Comment: Which documentation did you refer on iText website? Can you take a look at this link https://kb.itextpdf.com/home/it7kb/examples/merging-documents-and-create-a-table-of-contents

This link basically create TOC by merging the multiple documents and uses TreeMap to maintain page number and uses copyPagesTo method to copy all the pages to final document and finally create TOC by using TreeMap